# How to Include Test Results from TestNG when sending a Microsoft Teams MessageCard POST request

Tags: java, jenkins, testng, microsoft-teams, extentreports

I have a requirement to update a Microsoft teams channel with Test Results (**Success, Failure, Skipped**) after my test suite has completed, which consists of a Java/Maven/TestNG stack and uses extent reports (version 5.0.9) as the reporting tool.  Currently there is a Jenkins pipeline that sends a POST request to the teams channel via shell curl command, but since this is requirement requires the test results it seems like the course of action would be to use an httpClient to POST the request to the teams channel via the webhook and send these custom results along with the required teams fields.

How can this be done?  I have the below code which is in my @AfterMethod to increment the results for each status coming from each ITestResult (which I'm unsure how to use in the POST request), along with the current CURL command from Jenkins:

```
@AfterMethod
public void closure(ITestResult res) {
    try {
        if (res.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            String failScreenshotPath = ExtentCustom.getScreenshot(res.getName());
            ExtentCustom.eachTest.log(Status.FAIL, ExtentCustom.getFailFont("Snapshot below : " + res.getThrowable()),
                    MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(failScreenshotPath).build());
            success_tests++;
        } else if (res.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
            String passScreenshotPath = ExtentCustom.getScreenshot(res.getName());
            ExtentCustom.eachTest.log(Status.PASS, ExtentCustom.getPassFont("Snapshot below : "),
                    MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(passScreenshotPath).build());
            fail_tests++;
        } else {
            String skipScreenshotPath = ExtentCustom.getScreenshot(res.getName());
            ExtentCustom.eachTest.log(Status.SKIP, ExtentCustom.getSkipFont("Snapshot below : "),
                    MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(skipScreenshotPath).build());
            skip_tests++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

POST via CURL command in Jenkins:

```
sh("curl -v --location --request POST 'https://xyzco.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/c62020bd-2ad9-4a3a-84bb-65979f2d6873@bcfa3e87-841e-48c7-983b-584159dd1a69/IncomingWebhook/3281bd73bb4048229cac2c68d9dd28b7/1b2d22b1-e878-49b5-9f42-4c18d5bf853d' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{\"@type\": \"MessageCard\",\"@context\": \"http://schema.org/extensions\",\"themeColor\": \"#00FF00\",\"summary\": \"Weekend UI Validation Success\",\"sections\": [{\"activityTitle\": \"Weekend UI Validation Succesfull!!\",\"activitySubtitle\": \"Build Results\",\"activityImage\": \"https://ac-buckets-dev-acpublicmedia-2cxkd4j0deg1.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/GreenThumbUP.png\",\"facts\": [{\"name\": \"Message\",\"value\": \" Weekend UI Validation. Validation report: <a href=${Report_URL}> Click here </a>\"}, {\"name\": \"Status\",\"value\": \"Success\"},{\"name\": \"Job\",\"value\": \"${JOB_NAME}:${BUILD_NUMBER}\"}],\"markdown\": true}]}'")
```

Given this, I was thinking of creating method for this POST request using an http client such as Rest-Assured.  The details of the Report (${Report_URL}) comes from Jenkins using the publish html plugin.  How can I mimic something similar while also including the Test Results?  I am having a hard time finding any examples online, so just seeing if anyone has an suggestion.  Please let me know!